# When in a UCI race, does the helmet have to be to be fitted properly

Tags: safety, helmets, downhill, racing

I noticed that Nibali's helmet was very loose when he went down during one of the last stretches of the 2016 Giro d'Italia. A helmet is almost useless if it's not properly fastened. I understand that the pros loosen their helmets on the uphill to breathe more easily, but is there a rule about wearing it properly when at high speed?

Comment: So what's your question?  Are you asking "do pros have to wear helmets properly fitted?"  or "do pros loosen their helmets on uphills?" or "do helmets help at high speed?"

Comment: @Criggie: The question could be: How do the rules play if a rider loses his helmet during a race?

Comment: Question is if there is a rule how to wear the helmet, we don't need to talk about that a helmet is mandatory and if you have lost your helmet during the race, without accident, you won't get a pro (and not old). If you wear your helmet like Nibali did you can put it off, same security level and they where invented for security reasons.

Comment: @BitAccesser   Consider adding a photo to your question, to enhance your references.

Comment: @carel   OP never said "lose"  but did say "loosen"   so I *think* its about how they wear it, not whether they drop the helmet and leave it behind.  Waiting on OP to clarify.

Comment: Sorry, don't know exact words, but i assume that you have weared a bike helmet? If you can move it more than a few centimeters, it's not save, because if you fall down and your heads hits the ground, it shouldn't move away. What is correct description of the belt around your chin, that holds the helmet on your head?

Comment: @Criggie Didn't find a picture and I don't know, which stage.It was somewere at the end (15+) and it was a smaller group (maybe 15 riders) at downhill, but maybe it was just a nightmare ;)

Comment: I'm going to edit question to "When in a UCI race, does the helmet have to be to be fitted properly, or is it allowed to be loose for additional cooling?"   Does that suit?   Please voice objections if this is not correct.

Comment: Image searching for "nibali giro 2016 helmet" and various combinations of loose, poor fit, cooling, drop, breeze, wind   - no good images are coming up.  So please do your best to locate an image that demonstrates your question.

Comment: @Criggie according to [weather in Rome](http://www.accuweather.com/de/it/rome/213490/may-weather/213490) I would deny cooling purposes, even downhill, but first part sounds good. Thx I edit  myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## According to [UCI's official regulations](http://www.uci.ch/mm/Document/News/Rulesandregulation/17/68/12/1-GEN-20160603-EN_English.pdf)

#### Section 1.3.031

(emphasis mine)

> 1. Wearing a rigid safety helmet shall be mandatory during competitions and training
>      sessions in the following disciplines: track, mountain bike, cyclo-cross, trials and BMX,
>      para-cycling, as well as during cycling for all events.
> 2. During competitions on the road, a rigid safety helmet shall be worn.
>      During training on the road, the wearing of a rigid safety helmet is recommended. 
>      UCI CYCLING REGULATIONS
>      E0616 GENERAL ORGANISATION OF CYCLING AS A SPORT 74
>      However, riders must always comply with the legal provisions in this regard.
> 3. Each rider shall be responsible for:
>
>    - ensuring that the helmet is approved in compliance with an official security standard
>        and that the helmet can be identified as approved;
>    - wearing the helmet in accordance with the security regulations in order to ensure full
>        protection, including but not limited to a **correct adjustment on the head** as well as a
>        **correct adjustment of the chin strap**;
>    - avoiding any manipulation which could compromise the protective characteristics of the
>        helmet and not wearing a helmet which has been undergone manipulation or an incident
>        which might have compromised its protective characteristics;
>    - using only an approved helmet that has not suffered any accident or shock;
>    - using only a helmet that has not been altered or had any element added or removed in
>        terms of design or form.

By the letter of the law, Nibali could be punished for loosening his helmet strap at any point in competition.  Interestingly, USA cycling's regulations further clarify that "any point in competition" includes ANY time you are on a bike at an event, including warming up prior to race start and cooling down after the finish but before any awards ceremony (riding on rollers and trainers is exempt, however).

In reality I don't forsee any UCI officials wanting to punish one of the sport's premier athletes over something so minor; no one benefits by doing so, but it would cause anger and resentment amongst Nibali, his team, sponsors, and fans.  In the end, sometimes you have to pick and choose your battles.

That said, don't follow Nibali's lead here.  Wear your helmet properly or, as you say, it's entirely useless (not to mention, assuming you are not a WorldTour rider, you ARE liable to get disqualified by an overzealous local official).

Comment: Thx, very good! If I had used chin strap you would have understood? Getting your last paragraph right, I haven't dreamed it happend in real ( I watched 2 h on youtube and didn't find it, but wanted to cycle to italy ;)? Can you tell me, which stage?